# How do I scrape links and images from a website?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'm new to javascript and would like my first project to be this:

im trying to take the name of channels and thumbnails from [this site](http://vaughnlive.tv/browse) from source code using a javascript or php to display all thumbnails of channels on my website.

this is i want to catch the a href="this-link" and the img src but from all channels:

```
<div class="browseThumb">
                <a href="/realmanpwns" target="_top"><img src="//thumbnails.vaughnsoft.com/1427753239/fetch/live/realmanpwns.png" class"browseThumb" width="200" height="113" /></a>
                <div class="browseTxt" onclick="window.location = '/realmanpwns';">
                    <a href="/realmanpwns" target="_top" class="browseTxt">realmanpwns</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Any guidance for how to get started is appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code you've already tried toward the solution ...

Comment: i dont't have a code :(

Comment: Do a bit of research on web scraping with php and try something, then when you get stuck, we may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I used scrapy on a recent project. Didn't know python at the time but I've dabbled with a few other languages and it wasn't difficult to pick up.

They have a ton of resources to learn from.

Here's the direct link:
http://scrapy.org

PS. I am in no way affiliated with them, just a happy user.